# Javascript HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url

**Javascript:**

```
function tableToExcel() {

var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML;

window.location.href = "/Calendar/ExportData?calendar=" + calendar;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult ExportData(string calendar)
        {
            string headerTable = calendar;

            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Calendar" + ".xls;");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode; 
            Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

            Response.Write(headerTable);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

If i send document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML to ExportData by using window.location.href i am seeing below url exception

```
Request URL Too Long

HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.
```

I send parameter but browser gets parameter as url why ? And what i should do in order to solve this problem thanks ?

Answer (score 1):

**Max** URL size is **2,083** characters.

> As mentioned by @Brian, the HTTP clients (e.g. browsers) may have
>   their own limits, and HTTP servers will have different limits.
>   Microsoft Support says "Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in
>   Internet Explorer". IE has problems with URLs longer than that.

you should use post method for this, so:

this code create a form and append it to the body and submit it.

```
function tableToExcel() {
    var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML;

    var form = $('<form action="ExportData" method="post"><input type="text" name="calendar" /></form>')

    form.find('input').val(calendar);

    form.appendTo('body').submit();
}
```

I suggest you to add `[HttpPost]` attribute to your Action too.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportData(string calendar)
```